# Why doesn't it unify? Prolog issue

Tags: prolog, polynomials

I'm trying to do a predicate in prolog which substitute the value I give to the variables of the polynomial and then it calculate the result. Here is my code:

```
as_monomial(X, m(X, 0, [])) :- number(X), !.
as_monomial(^(Y, Z), m(1, Z, [v(Z, Y)])) :- !.
as_monomial(*(X, ^(Y, Z)), m(G, K, Q)) :- as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), K is (TD + Z), compress_monomial([v(Z, Y)| Vars], A), ordina_m(A, Q), !.
as_monomial(*(X, Y), m(G, K, Q)) :- as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), K is (TD + 1), compress_monomial([v(1, Y)| Vars], A), ordina_m(A, Q), !.
as_monomial(-(X), m(-A, Y, L)) :- as_monomial(X, m(A, Y, L)).
as_monomial(X, m(1, 1, [v(1, X)])).

ordina_m(List, Sorted) :- sort(2, @=<, List,  Sorted).
ordina_var(List, Sorted) :- sort(0, @=<, List, Sorted).

compress_monomial([], []) :- !.
compress_monomial([X| Xs], A2) :- compress_monomial(Xs, A), compress_monomial2(X, A, A2), !.

is_monomial(m(_C, TD, VPs)) :- integer(TD), TD >= 0, is_list(VPs).

is_polynomial(poly(M)) :- is_list(M), foreach(member(Monomio, M), is_monomial(Monomio)).

variables(Poly1, Result) :- is_polynomial(Poly1), variabili(Poly1, Result), !.
variables(Poly1, Result) :- as_polynomial(Poly1, Result1), variabili(Result1, Result), !.

variabili(poly([]), []) :- !.
variabili(poly([m(_, _, [])| Xs]), Ys) :- variabili(poly(Xs), Ys), !.
variabili(poly([m(X, Y, [v(_, A)| Vs])| Xs]), Z) :- variabili(poly([m(X, Y, Vs)| Xs]), Ys), ordina_var([A| Ys], R), compressV(R, Z),  !.

compressV([], []).
compressV([X|T],[X|T1]):- member(X,T),!,canc(X,T,R), compressV(R,T1).
compressV([X|T],[X|T1]) :- compressV(T,T1).

canc(_L, [], []).
canc(L, [L|S], Z) :- canc(L, S, Z).
canc(L, [H|S], [H|Z]):- canc(L, S, Z), !.

as_polynomial(+(X, Y), poly(C)) :- as_monomial(Y, G), as_polynomial(X, poly(Gs)), compress_polynomial([G| Gs], C), !.
as_polynomial(-(X, Y), poly(C)) :- as_monomial(-Y, G), as_polynomial(X, poly(Gs)), compress_polynomial([G| Gs], C), !.
as_polynomial(X, poly([X])) :- is_monomial(X), !.
as_polynomial(X, poly([Q])) :- as_monomial(X, Q), !.

compress_polynomial([], []) :- !.
compress_polynomial([X| Xs], A2) :- compress_polynomial(Xs, A), compress_polynomial2(X, A, A2), !.

compress_polynomial2(m(X, Y, Z), [], [m(X, Y, Z)]) :- !.
compress_polynomial2(m(X, Y, Z), [m(X1, Y, Z)| Xs], [m(X2, Y, Z)| Xs]) :- X2 is (X + X1), !.
compress_polynomial2(X, [Y| Ys], [Y| Z]) :- compress_polynomial2(X, Ys, Z), !.

polyval(Poly1, V, Result) :- is_polynomial(Poly1), variables(Poly1, Vars), poly_val(Poly1, Vars, V, Result), !.
polyval(Poly1, V, Result) :- as_polynomial(Poly1, P1), variables(P1, Vars), poly_val(P1, Vars, V, Result), !.

poly_val(poly([]), , , poly([])) :- !.
poly_val(poly([m(X, Y, Z)| Xs]), Vars, V, poly([R| Ys])) :- poly_val(poly(Xs), Vars, V, poly(Ys)), print(m(X, Y, Z)), mon_val(m(X, Y, Z), Vars, V, R), !.

mon_val(m(X, Y, []), [_], [_], m(X, Y, [])) :- !.
mon_val(m(X, Y, [v(W, Z)| Vs]), [Z| Vs2], [Val| Vvs], m(X2, Y2, Z2)) :- integer(Val), mon_val(m(X, Y, Vs), Vs2, Vvs, m(X3, Y2, Z2)), X2 is (X3 * (Val ^ W)), !.
mon_val(m(X, Y, [v(W, Z)| Vs]), [_| Vs2], [_| Vvs], m(X, Y2, Z2)) :- mon_val(m(X, Y, [v(W, Z)| Vs]), Vs2, Vvs, m(X, Y3, Z2)), Y2 is (Y3 + W), !.
```

I hope I put all the code you need to prove it, in case please say it to me and I apologise for it. I know about the cut but, at the moment, it is just a trial. My problem is in mon_val because it looks like doesn't want to unify. An example of query I use is **polyval(x+x+y, [1, 3], Q).** where the output is "false" and it should return **poly(m(1, 0, []), m(1, 0, []), m(3, 0, []))**. Are you able to help me doing that? I just want to solve the problem and later I will also implement the sum between the numbers which is pretty easy with the rest of the code I have. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna know, at the end I solve the problem myself (which is, according some of you, the best way to learn and I'm agree). So my poly-val becomes:

```
polyval(Poly1, V, Result) :- is_polynomial(Poly1), variables(Poly1, Vars), poly_val(Poly1, Vars, V, Result), !.
polyval(Poly1, V, Result) :- as_polynomial(Poly1, P1), variables(P1, Vars), poly_val(P1, Vars, V, Result), !.

poly_val(poly([]), _, _, poly([])) :- !.
poly_val(poly([X| Xs]), Vars, V, poly(Z)) :- poly_val(poly(Xs), Vars, V, poly(Ys)), mon_val(X, Vars, V, R), compress_polynomial([R| Ys], Z), !.

/* mon_val(Monomio, Variabili, ValoreVariabili, Result) */

mon_val(m(X, _, []), [_], [_], m(X,0, [])) :- !.
mon_val(m(X, _, Z), [], [], m(X,0, Z)) :- !.
mon_val(m(X, Y, [v(W, Z) | R]), [Z| Vs], [Val|Vvs], m(X2, Y2, Z2)) :- integer(Val), mon_val(m(X, Y, R), Vs, Vvs, m(X3, Y2, Z2)), X2 is (X3 * (Val ^ W)), !.
mon_val(m(X, Y, Z), [_|Vs2], [_| Vvs], m(X2, Y2, A)) :- mon_val(m(X, Y, Z), Vs2, Vvs, m(X2, Y2, A)), !.`
```